# Problemas com utilização do JsBarcode e PHP

Tags: php, javascript

Estou com problemas para utilizar o JsBarcode e PHP.
Eu gero dinamicamente os códigos através de uma lista. Mas ao utilizar o código
dentro do loop do código de barras que é o seguinte:

```
<img id="barcode"/>
        <script>
        var codigo = '<?php echo $codigo_barra['codigo_barras'];?>';
        JsBarcode("#barcode", codigo , {
          displayValue:true,
          fontSize:24,
          lineColor: "#0cc"
        });
        </script>
```

ele gera repetidamente somente 1 código sendo que tenho 4 códigos diferentes gerados na variável `$codigo_barra['codigo_barras']`. O que estou fazendo de errado nesse caso?

Abaixo o código completo da página.

```
<html>
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/etiquetas.css">
  <script src='js/JsBarcode.all.min.js'></script>

</head>
<body>
  <?php foreach($codigo_barras as $codigo_barra):
    ?>
    <div class="card" style="width: 18rem;">
  <div class="card-body">
    <table>
  <tr>
    <td>
      <div><h2><?=$codigo_barra['desc_produto'];?></h2></div>
      <input type="hidden" name="codigo_barras" value="<?=$codigo_barra['codigo_barras'];?>">
    </td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>
      <table class="table table-bordered">
     <tr>
       <?php
       $produtos_grade = buscaCompraProdutoGrade($conexao, $id_compra, $codigo_barra['id_sequencia']);
       foreach ($produtos_grade as $produto_grade):
        ?>
       <td>
         <div class="form-group">
         <div><kbd><label for="inputCity">
         <?=$produto_grade['tamanho'];?></label>
         </kbd><br>
         <b><label for="inputCity"><?=$produto_grade['quantidade'];?></label></b>
       </div>
     </div>
       </td>
     <?php endforeach ?>
     </tr>
     </table>
    </td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>
      <div>Data previsão: <b><?php
      $data = date_create($codigo_barra['previsao']);
      echo date_format($data,'d/m/Y');?>
    </b></div>
    </td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>
      <div>
        <img id="barcode"/>
        <script>
        var codigo = '<?php echo $codigo_barra['codigo_barras'];?>';
        JsBarcode("#barcode", codigo , {
          displayValue:true,
          fontSize:24,
          lineColor: "#0cc"
        });
        </script>
        <?php echo $codigo_barra['codigo_barras'];?>
      </div>
    </td>
  </tr>
  </table>
</div>
</div>
<?php endforeach; ?>
</body>
```

Comment: Sem saber como você gerou o valor de `$codigo_barra['codigo_barras']`, como ficou o valor gerado e como deveria ficar será impossível responder.

Comment: Editei a pergunta com código completo

Comment: `id` deve ser único, você está repetindo o `id` `barcode`. E a função `JSBarcode` está apontada fixa para um único `id`

Comment: so que se eu coloco o código de barras como próprio id e jogo na função JsBarcode da o erro: JsBarcode.all.min.js:2 Uncaught DOMException: Failed to execute 'querySelectorAll' on 'Document': '#000120000001000063002001' is not a valid selector. Ou seja,, a própria biblioteca faz um querySelectorAll

Comment: O ID utilizado é invalido para o CSS, veja essa thread: https://github.com/DevExpress/testcafe/issues/1899#issuecomment-338203498 ou nesse link: https://www.w3.org/TR/CSS21/syndata.html#value-def-identifier

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ao que parece, seu problema é uma questão do seletor sendo utilizado incorretamente.

Você tem duas formas de resolver o seu problema.

A primeiro é criar um id único para cada vez que realizar o loop:

```
foreach($codigo_barras as $key => $codigo_barra):
    $idBarcode = "barcode{$key}";
```

E, substituir o id fixo:

```
<img id="<?= $idBarcode; ?>"/>
    <script>
    var codigo = '<?php echo $codigo_barra['codigo_barras'];?>';
    JsBarcode("#<?= $idBarcode; ?>", codigo , {
      displayValue:true,
      fontSize:24,
      lineColor: "#0cc"
    });
</script>
```

Outra, é utilizar as propriedades `jsbarcode-*`e a função `init` da bibiblioteca:

```
<img class="barcode"
  jsbarcode-value="<?= $codigo_barra['codigo_barras']; ?>"
  jsbarcode-fontSize="24"
  jsbarcode-lineColor= "#0cc" />
```

Basta inicializar com o seguinte comando:

```
JsBarcode(".barcode").init();
```

Como os valores estão diretamente na tag HTML e está utilizando a `class` `barcode`, não terá problema algum.

CodePen: https://codepen.io/gabrielheming/pen/RByppa

Comment: Cara, essa primeira opção de substituir o id fixo funcionou perfeitamente. Muito obrigado. Abraços.

Comment: Ambas as opções funcionam, fica apenas pela praticidade de escolher uma ou outra.